# Javascript: multi level menu slide on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

Could you help me with this code?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  /* Panel Slide */
  var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btnBorder");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    var panel = btn[i].nextSibling;
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      $(".btnBorder").hide();
      panel.show();
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="menu" class="sector-row">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="btnBorder flex">Logo <i class="ml-auto fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
          <ul class="slide-panel">
              demo
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btnBorder flex">Navigazione <i class="ml-auto fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btnBorder flex">Widgets <i class="ml-auto fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btnBorder flex">Footer <i class="ml-auto fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I would like to make a menu slide with multi level but the element "slide-panel" is not showing up...

Comment: slide-panel is a ul element inside another ul element?  What do you click on to make this ul element show up?  It looks like your trying to add an event listener on 4 divs with the class name btnBorder?  What does panel.show() do?

Comment: as you can see if I click the button btnBorder I need to show up the element ul as next element of that button.

Comment: So, panel is the nextSibling of each button?  Try console.log (panel)  Is there an error message?

Comment: Yep: panel.show() is not a function

Comment: That should help you. You need a show() function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of mixing pure javascript with jquery .. so the next code is in jquery .. Also I prefer to use `add/remove/toggleClass` instead of `hide/show()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btnBorder').on('click' , function(e){
    var ul_selector = $(this).next('ul.slide-panel'); // OR $(this).closest('li').find('ul.slide-panel');
    e.stopPropagation(); // it will prevent the parent click if you've one
    $('ul.slide-panel').not(ul_selector).addClass('hide'); // if you need to hide other slide-panels 
    ul_selector.toggleClass('hide'); // toggle the class hide which in css is display:none and added to the slide-panel html element
  });
});
```

```css
.slide-panel.hide{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" class="sector-row">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="btnBorder flex">Logo <i class="ml-auto fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
      <ul class="slide-panel hide">
        Demo
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="btnBorder flex">Navigazione <i class="ml-auto fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="btnBorder flex">Widgets <i class="ml-auto fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="btnBorder flex">Footer <i class="ml-auto fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Note:** The problem when using `.next()` if the element has `<!-- -->` or `</br>` it will not select the correct element .. So you can use `.closest().find()` you'll find it in my code above

Comment: Hi, I've tried the new code and it's totally working. :)  Could you help me with this line code?
`var logo = $('#logo').val();
  var myLogo = document.getElementById('title-logo');
  myLogo.innerText = logo;`

Comment: @Fabbro `#logo` if input or select use `.val()` else use `.text()` and `var myLogo =  $('#title-logo');` to set a text   `myLogo.text(logo);`